# Only echo item in foreach with highest value

Tags: php

I am trying to get the highest number from a set of SKUs in WordPress. I have the below code which gets a list of all SKUs. I am then only showing the ones which contain the string `'BUR'` and then I am using `explode` to trim the output. Based on the below what is the best method?

Example Data:

```
ABB-0001-1
ABB-0002-1
ABB-0003-1
BUR-0001-1
BUR-0002-1
BUR-0003-1
```

Current Code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('product'), 
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$wcProductsArray = get_posts($args);

if (count($wcProductsArray)) {
    foreach ($wcProductsArray as $productPost) {
        $productSKU = get_post_meta($productPost->ID, '_sku', true);
        $productTitle = get_the_title($productPost->ID);
            if (strpos($productSKU, 'BUR') !== false) { 
                $s = explode("-",$productSKU);
                echo '<li>' . $s[1] . '</li>';
            }
    }
}
?>
```

Current Output:

```
0003
0002
0001
```

Desired Output:

```
0003
```

Comment: This sounds like a general PHP question than a WordPress question. Throw them in an array and [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) them.

Comment: Has this question been resolved? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this is more of a general PHP question rather than a WordPress question which should be on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) instead.

To `echo` only the highest value from your `array`, try storing your items (`$s[1]`) [into an array instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3045647/6579923) and then use [`max()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php). Something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('product'), 
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$wcProductsArray = get_posts($args);
$skuList = array();

if (count($wcProductsArray)) {
    foreach ($wcProductsArray as $productPost) {
        $productSKU = get_post_meta($productPost->ID, '_sku', true);
        $productTitle = get_the_title($productPost->ID);
            if (strpos($productSKU, 'BUR') !== false) { 
                $s = explode("-",$productSKU);
                // echo '<li>' . $s[1] . '</li>';
                $skuList[] = $s[1];
            }
    }
}

echo( max($skuList) );
```

I don't have a WooCommerce setup right now to validate it, so you'll need to confirm that it works or play around with it.

Comment: Modified it so that my echo looked like yours but the output was just a list of empty list items

Comment: @BenH Updated answer

Comment: @BenH Did you get a chance to look at my updated answer?